# How to store and access 2 different types of List in a HashMap

Tags: java, list, dictionary, arraylist, hashmap

Im trying to store and access 2 different types of List in a HashMap, and access them when the method that return the HashMap is it called, but Im getting this error:
`The constructor ArrayList<JournalArticle>(Object) is undefined`
The method looks like this:

```
public static HashMap<String, Object> getJournalArticles(long groupId) throws NumberFormatException, SystemException{
    List<JournalArticle> journalArticles = JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.getStructureArticles(groupId);
    List<String> allJournalArticleIds = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (JournalArticle journalArticle : journalArticles) {
        allJournalArticleIds.add(journalArticle.getArticleId());
    }

    HashMap<String, Object> mapArticles = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    mapArticles.put("journalArticles", journalArticles);
    mapArticles.put("allJournalArticleIds", allJournalArticleIds);

    return mapArticles;
}
```

And when I call the method and try to store their respective values into a new List I get the error commented before:

```
HashMap<String, Object> mapArticles = JournalArticleUtil.getJournalArticles(scopeGroupId);
List<JournalArticle> allArticles = new ArrayList<JournalArticle>(mapArticles.get("journalArticles"));
List<String> allJournalArticleIds = new ArrayList<String>(mapArticles.get("allJournalArticleIds"));
```

What´s wrong and how to solve?

Comment: What's wrong is obvious (the compiler complains about it)... How to solve it? Probably time to use a custom class instead of a map (methinks).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a class written to hold this information (you may find it quicker to use something like [`Pair<L, R>`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.9/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/Pair.html)):

```
class ArticleHolder {
    private List<JournalArticle> journalArticles;
    private List<String> allJournalArticleIds;

    public ArticleHolder(List<JournalArticle> journalArticles,
        List<String> allJournalArticleIds) {
        this.journalArticles = journalArticles;
        this.allJournalArticleIds = allJournalArticleIds;
    }

    //getters + setters
}
```

And change your methods:

```
public static ArticleHolder getJournalArticles(long groupId) 
    throws NumberFormatException, SystemException {

    List<JournalArticle> journalArticles = 
                JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.getStructureArticles(groupId);
    List<String> allJournalArticleIds = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (JournalArticle journalArticle : journalArticles) {
        allJournalArticleIds.add(journalArticle.getArticleId());
    }

    return new ArticleHolder(journalArticles, allJournalArticleIds);
}
```

*Beside that*: your call to `new ArrayList<JournalArticle>(...)` shows that you intended to create **new** array list instances (assuming code could compile). There should be no need to do that, even if your map values were typed as `Collection` objects.

Comment: This is a great solution! I'm waiting for Tupples in Java Core as vavr has.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO The quick solution is change the type of mapArticles to this `HashMap<String, List<?>>` and then:

```
List<JournalArticle> allArticles = new ArrayList<JournalArticle>((Collection<JournalArticle>)mapArticles.get("journalArticles"));
List<String> allJournalArticleIds = new ArrayList<String>((Collection<String>)mapArticles.get("allJournalArticleIds"));
```

Because the ArrayList constructor only supports these options:

```
 new ArrayList<T>();
 new ArrayList<T>(int capacity);
 new ArrayList<T>(Collection<? extends T> collection);
```

And `Object` isn't a collection at compiling time.

Comment: @SilverSurfer It's quick but ernest_k's solution is better.

Comment: Its better in terms of efficency? Its faster? Do you think I should accept his answer for future visitors? Is it bad a bad practise If I use your answer?

Comment: @SilverSurfer It's more clean. I think you should accept his answer.